# Herança em Banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, herança

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, onde eu tenho 3 tabelas que possuem os mesmos atributos, porém como tinham atributos nessas tabelas que eram obrigatórios para uns, e não para outros, eu resolvi separar em 3 tabelas diferentes. Entretanto, estou tendo alguns problemas para desenvolver algumas funções que são comuns as 3 tabelas.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de transformar essas 3 tabelas em uma só? Lembrando que eu possuo modelos de validação de dados diferentes para cada tabela, então eu acho que não poderia simplesmente sumir com as outras duas.

Estou utilizando asp.net mvc 4 e entity framework com database first.

```
Table Usuario

    [IdUsuario] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomeCompleto] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Senha] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Sexo] char(1)  NULL,
    [Telefone] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [About] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [Nickname] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Email2] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Endereco] varchar(100)  NULL,
    [Bairro] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [Estado] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [Cep] varchar(11)  NULL,
    [Celular] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [FotoPerfil] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [StatusPerfil] varchar(100)  NULL,
    [NBans] int  NULL,
    [Banido] bit  NULL,
    [DtCadastro] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [DtNasc] datetime  NOT NULL

Table Banca 

    [IdBanca] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomeCompleto] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Cpf] char(11)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Rg] char(8)  NOT NULL,
    [Senha] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Sexo] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [DtNasc] datetime  NULL,
    [Telefone] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [About] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [Nickname] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Email2] varchar(100)  NULL,
    [Endereco] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Bairro] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Estado] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Cep] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Celular] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Foto] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [FormAcademica] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [DtCadastro] datetime  NOT NULL

Table Desginer
    [IdDesigner] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomeCompleto] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Cpf] char(11)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Rg] char(8)  NOT NULL,
    [Senha] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Sexo] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [DtNasc] datetime  NULL,
    [Telefone] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [About] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [Nickname] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [Email2] varchar(100)  NULL,
    [Endereco] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Bairro] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Estado] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Cep] varchar(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Celular] varchar(45)  NULL,
    [Foto] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [DtCadastro] datetime  NULL
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de como são suas tabelas hoje, editando sua pergunta?

Comment: Você informou que está "....tendo alguns problemas para desenvolver algumas funções...." mas não explicou qual o problema você precisa resolver, quais métodos você quer criar para resolver um problema do seu negócio, nem como estão as tabelas. Dica: pense no seu negócio primeiramente, o que vai acontecer com a modelagem das tabelas é consequência.

Comment: Só pra especificar, o problema que você tenta resolver tem a ver com uma coisa chamada **normalização de dados**. P.S.: eu não sou o mesmo Renan do comentário anterior.

Comment: Na verdade, o "problema para desenvolver algumas funções" é que em certos metodos que são comuns as tres tabelas, eu tenho que fazer consultas e ifs e elses, o que acaba deixando o codigo um pouco extenso, o que me incomoda um pouco... Vou editar a pergunta com as minhas tabelas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editado.

Comment: Há algum problema se eu sumir com as outras duas tabelas e deixar apenas a tabela usuario?

Comment: Design e Banca é um tipo de Usuario? Caso positivo você pode usar uma tabela somente com os dados em comum. Assim você criaria um campo a mais nessa tabela (TipoUsuario) por exemplo.

Comment: Sim. São usuarios que possuem funções de acordo com suas roles. Por exemplo, Banca é responsavel por monitorar o site, eles podem excluir as postagens, escrever artigos, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi Design e Banca são tipos de Usuario.

Você pode usar uma tabela somente e criar um campo a mais nessa tabela (TipoUsuario por exemplo), para identificar o tipo do usuário.

Esse campo pode inclusive facilitar a implementação das suas regras de negócio relacionadas aos usuários, por exemplo:

```
var usuario = _repositorio.ObterUsuarioPorId(id);

if(usuario.TipoUsuario == EnumTipoUsuario.Design)
{
    //regra para usuário tipo Design
}

if(usuario.TipoUsuario == EnumTipoUsuario.Banca)
{
    //regra para usuário tipo Banca
}
```

> ...Lembrando que eu possuo modelos de validação de dados diferentes para cada tabela, então eu acho que não poderia simplesmente sumir com as outras duas...

Na verdade, analisando as informações da pergunta, acredito que você tenha validações de dados diferentes para cada **tipo de objeto usuário**. Se for um usuário do tipo Design valido isso/faço tal lógica, se for usuário do tipo Banca preciso validar aquilo. Mas a tabela é a mesma, estamos falando de usuário.

Comment: Se as tabelas não fossem separadas, era possível usar a herança em código mesmo, mas para este caso sua resposta funciona perfeitamente.